# Why local array in function could not take an inconstant parameter? in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

For example, in a function, "a" array and "first" array (normally arrays cannot take an integer as a parameter which is not const) can take "d"  and "a1" as parameter). My question is that why this works like that, what is the difference between them?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class BC {
    int first[];
    int modify(int a[], int d) {
        int a1;
        a[a1];
        first[a1];
        int sec[a1];
        //a[d];
        //first[d];
        //sec[d];

    }
};
```

Comment: Your example is incorrect, but apparently you're asking about the g++ language extension where a raw array can be declared with size known only at runtime. That's called a variable length array or VLA, and comes from C99. It's an abomination.

Comment: You are using `a1` without initializing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a[a1]; // This is not an array declaration.  This is referring to the a1-th element of the array.
first[a1]; // Same as above
int sec[a1]; // This IS a declaration and so SHOULD fail because a1 is non-const.
```

To further illuminate, you could say

```
a[a1] = 5;
```

or

```
int x = a[a1];
```

When you write

```
a[a1];
```

you are referring to an element of an array, but without doing anything with the value.  This is allowed even though it seems pointless.  Potentially, the [] operator can be overidden and hence this statement COULD do something.  That's why it's allowed.

Comment: Thank you, let me ask you last thing, when i write int sec[a1]; i create an array with bound a1? if yes, i can declare an array without bound an then give a number to specific element of it.? For example: int first[]; first[5]=2;

Comment: @Shahriyar, in int sec[a1], a1 must be const.  But yes to the second part.  You can access any element of any array - no bounds checking is done on these types of arrays.  Also look at std::vector which lets you work more easily with arrays when you don't know the size in advance.